# Printing Calendar Sideways with the use of Calendar API

Tags: printing, calendar, format

Hi guys So i have this problem.. i wanted to print a calendar, utilizing the Calendar API.

condition:
user inputs a Year, anInteger between 1000 - 9999.
then it will output the calendar of that year and 2 more succeeding years.
so if i input 2012 it will  output the Calendar of 2012 , 2013 and 2014.
here is the catch it must be SIDEWAYS!

```
package lessons;

import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lesson3 {
    static String[] days = {"SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"};
    static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GregorianCalendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Year: ");
        int input = scanner.nextInt(); //month input


        //System.out.print("YEAR (): ");
        //int input2 = scanner.nextInt();

        scanner.close();



        int year = input;
        gcal.set(Calendar.YEAR,input);

        for(int monthCount = 0;monthCount<12;monthCount++){

            gcal.set(Calendar.MONTH,monthCount); // month counter 0 - 11 producing jan to dec.
            monthCheck(monthCount); // converting months to readable names

            int x = gcal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            int max = gcal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            for(int i = 0;i<days.length;i++){
                System.out.printf("%8s",days[i]);

            }
            System.out.println("");




            for(int i = 0; i < x-1;i++){
                System.out.printf("%8s","");
                counter++;
                if(counter%7==0){
                    System.out.println("");
                }


            }

            for(int i = 1;i<=max;i++){
                System.out.printf("%8s",i);
                counter++;
                if(counter%7==0){
                    System.out.println("");
                }

            }
            System.out.println("");
            //System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
    static void monthCheck(int monthCount){

        ArrayList monthsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
        for (int i = 0; i < months.length-1; i++) {
          String monthArr = months[i];
          monthsList.add(months[i]);

        }
        System.out.println(months[monthCount]);

    }





}
```

[This is what i can do with the code Above, click here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QhSN.png)

[this is what i am aiming for now. CLICK HERE!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akEFc.png)

Comment: your code only prints till december of 2012.

Comment: yes yes, it is coded tht way at first.
no input yet, i can do that kind of code i can code any given year now, i just can't upload it yet.
so out of this code, lets juts say the year will always be 2012,2013 and 14.
how can i print it all?